# get data from different tables based on the value which is a common field of all the tables

Tags: sql, cakephp

I've 5 tables..,

Activity, Users, Admin, Individual, Employer

Activity, Admin, Individual, Employer belongs to Users table as shown

```
Activity          Admin                 Individual              Employer
+-----------+    +------------------+   +------------------+    +------------------+
id | user_id     id | user_id | name    id | user_id | name     id | user_id | name
+-----------+    +------------------+   +------------------+    +------------------+
```

Now, I'm firing the query on the `Activity` table,

If the `user_id` value is in `Admin` table then I need to get the name from `Admin` table,
If the `user_id` value is in `Employer` table then I need to get the name from `Employer` table,
similarly if the `user_id` value is in `Individual` table then I need to get the name from `Individual` table,

Comment: do you have tried INNER JOIN for doing this.

Comment: Where is the query you are firing? Show the code. For wich RDBM's, MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, postgre?

Comment: @F1beta - yeah its already inner join

Comment: @Yaroslav - sry, I cannot show it because I'm using grid to get the data for all the modules, I'm writing the fields,conditions,joins & others for each module separately & finally using the grid

Answer (score 2):

Try with this concept :

```
SELECT 
    A.ID AS ID
    A.User_id AS UserID
    A.Name AS Name
    'Admin' AS TableName
FROM Admin A INNER JOIN Activity B 
ON A.User_Id=B.User_Id

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    A.ID AS ID
    A.User_id AS UserID
    A.Name AS Name
    'Individual' AS TableName
FROM Individual A INNER JOIN Activity B 
ON A.User_Id=B.User_Id

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    A.ID AS ID
    A.User_id AS UserID
    A.Name AS Name
    'Employer' AS TableName
FROM Employer A INNER JOIN Activity B 
ON A.User_Id=B.User_Id
```

Comment: Hi Anu  I have one question related it ...May these query not work for postgres sql ?

Comment: I think this would be work because SQL is standard language , Many of database follow SQL standard .

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE`. Something like this:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  COALESCE(d.name, i.name, e.name) AS userName
FROM Activity        AS a
LEFT JOIN admin      AS d ON a.user_id = d.user_id
LEFT JOIN Individual AS i ON a.user_id = i.user_id
LEFT JOIN Employer   AS e ON a.user_id = e.user_id;
```